# Using `git submodule update`

Tags: git

Let's say I have `project_a` (git repo), which contains files & another `project_b` (git repo).

```
project_a
 --> files
 --> project_b
```

As the [git-scm](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) book demonstrates, I can run:

```
cd project_a
git submodule init
git submodule update // clones project_b repo specified in '.gitsubmodules'
```

to populate the initially empty `project_b` directory within `project_a`.

Rather than run `git submodule update` to get the latest from `project_b`, I'd prefer to clone the latest version of `project_b` at a point in time, and then have `project_a` only use that version (unless, of course, I do a `git pull` in `project_b`).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're describing is exactly how submodules already work in git.  If you don't update the hash for the submodule and check it in to `project_a`, you'll always use the same revision of `project_b`.

Comment: so if I do the following: (1) make `project_a` (2) `git submodule add project_b` (3) `git add .gitattributes project_b` (4) `git commit -m "added project_b repo"` (5) `git push origin master`. Then any `git clone project_a`, followed by `git submodule init && git submodule update` will have the same original `project_b`? (even if project_b's official repo had 5 more commits)?

Comment: Yes, that's what will happen.

Comment: so, if I want to include those 5 updates from `project_b`, I'd need to (1) cd to `project_a/project_b` (2) `git pull origin master` (3) `cd ..` (4) `git commit -m "got latest from project_b"` (5) `git push origin master`? Then, anyone who does `git clone project_a && cd project_a && git submodule init && git submodule update` will have a `project_b` including those 5 changes?

Answer (score 0):

This is the method you should use for bringing in a submodule:

1. `cd project_a`
2. `git submodule add https://url/to/repository relative/path/to/save/repository/to`
3. `cd relative/path/to/save/repository/to`
4. `git checkout desired_commit`
5. `cd -` (return to the previous directory)
6. `git add relative/path/to/save/repository/to`
7. `git commit` (whenever you commit to a parent directory it records the current commit that all submodules are on).

If you want to change the commit of the submodule at anytime, you just change to that directory and work with it like normal. Just make sure that you always have it on a commit that is pushed to it's origin. Otherwise, you can get into a situation where the parent repository is pointing to a commit that doesn't exist in the real repository.

Comment: It seems like a hassle for people who `git clone` the parent_repo to have to run `git submodule update`. But I suppose there's no alternative, right?

Comment: That is correct. If you use submodules often, it becomes second nature to do that after a fresh clone. Also, cloning a new repot isn't a very common task for most people. If you want to make it a little easier you could include the necessary commands in a "setup" script in the parent repot.